# Susy compile time slow

Tags: ruby, performance, sass, susy

I am using susy version 2.1.3 and since upgrading from version 1 where my compile time was less than 1 second it now takes 7s+

```
[22:30:46] Finished 'sass' after 8 s
```

I have updated all gems to latest + beta versions to see if it speeds anything up but with no luck, I have reverted back to older versions, but always version 2 as it doesn't depend on compass, with no luck either.

How can I speed up the compile time, if at all?

Answer (score 0):

Performance regressions are a known issue in the latest versions of Sass. We're working on some small performance enhancements in Susy, and preparing for LibSass compatibility, but I'm not sure of any clear actions you can take (besides possibly contributing to Sass).

Comment: This makes me excited! I really love Susy but have been bummed that it's introduced 10+ second compile times to a few projects I've used it on. I don't know Ruby, but please let me know if there's any way I can help :)

Comment: I don't know Ruby either. :) Susy is written in pure Sass, so working on Susy doesn't require any ruby knowledge. There are a lot of ideas happening in the [issue thread](https://github.com/ericam/susy/issues/325) but none have been properly implemented yet. You're welcome to contribute!